# Best possible way to get the ClientID from Cognito

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-cognito

In my `Cognito` setup where I have created multiple sets of userpools and client ids.
Each userpools will contains certain amounts of users and their scope is limited to their respective clientIds.

Now I have created 3 different lambdas, and link those lambdas to Api gateway.
Those lambda's and API end point path looks like `signup`, `confirm-signup`, `forgot-password`, `confirm-password`.

I have my python ready working forne client id and one user pool exist, these lambda's work fine. and I hardcoded my clientid.
e.g.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    for field in ["username", "email", "password", "name"]:
        if not event.get(field):
            return {"error": False, "success": True, 'message': f"{field} is not present", "data": None}
    username = event['username']
    email = event["email"]
    password = event['password']
    name = event["name"]
    client = boto3.client('cognito-idp')

client.sign_up(
            ClientId=CLIENT_ID,
            SecretHash=get_secret_hash(username),
            Username=username,
            Password=password, 
            UserAttributes=[
            {
                'Name': "name",
                'Value': name
            },
            {
                'Name': "email",
                'Value': email
            }
            ],
            ValidationData=[
                {
                'Name': "email",
                'Value': email
            },
            {
                'Name': "custom:username",
                'Value': username
            }
])
```

and this client-id is referring to the user pool where this client-id belongs to.
As a part of boto3 client-id is mandatory to call `sign-up`.

So, now my problem is I have 2 userpool and 2 client-ids.

```
userpoolA-clientIdA
userpoolB-clinetIdB
```

so, now for `signup` API call I'm passing ["username", "email", "password", "name", "userpoolA"]
Now my question is how to get `clientIdA` in lambda for `userpoolA` so that I can call the `sign-up` mthod and add this username to that `userpoolA`.

Yes, this is necessary, we need to segregate the user's in such way that poolA users can't and won't eligible to access poolB token or authorization.

I see [describe_user_pool](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html#CognitoIdentityProvider.Client.describe_user_pool) but as a input it needs UserPoolId not userpoolName. If anyone can suggest the best approach will be really appreciated.

Comment: So, users sign up using the same API to different user pools, right? Who decides the user pool? What is the rule?

Comment: @HernánAlarcón yes, user sign up In the same API, by giving the input as `userpool, username, password, email address. So literally based on user pool, lambda should create these user details in that pool. We initially created a pool/clientid and requested users when they need to signup they have to give the user pool an additional input along with the username and password.